# listview.cpp(124) : error C2065: 'LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER' : undeclared identifier

Tags: listview, winapi, sdk

i  have succeeded creating a 'listview" use WINAPI. However after i add  LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER style and debug my programme , it show me an error : "listview.cpp(124) : error C2065: 'LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER' : undeclared identifier", i dont find any help by google. Why do it appear?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx#macros_for_conditional_declarations

Comment: you need have `NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP`  . include `sdkddkver.h`

Comment: thanks, i have solved it with another  method. it just add  a "#define " definition.